# Problem with Collection::sortBy() in cakephp 4

Tags: sorting, cakephp, collections, cakephp-4.x

I'm trying to sort a list of email accounts by alphabetical order using `Collection::sortBy()` in cakephp 4, but it seems not working the way I use it.

```php
$accounts = [
          [
            'email' => 'webmaster@example.com',
            'isBlocked' => false,
          ],
          [
            'email' => 'dom@example.com',
            'isBlocked' => false,
          ],
          [
            'email' => 'me@example.com',
            'isBlocked' => false,
          ],
          [
            'email' => 'guy@example.com',
            'isBlocked' => false,
          ],
          [
            'email' => 'test@example.com',
            'isBlocked' => false,
          ]
        ];

$sorted = collection($accounts)
            ->sortBy('email', SORT_ASC)
            ->toArray();

debug($sorted);
```

`debug($sorted)` returns exactly the same array as `$accounts`...

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default sort type is `SORT_NUMERIC`, and converted to numbers, all your strings will be `0`, hence all are equal as seen by the sorting mechanism, and nothing will chance.

For strings use `SORT_NATURAL`, `SORT_STRING`, `SORT_LOCALE_STRING`, or `SORT_REGULAR`, eg:

```php
sortBy('email', SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL)
```

The Cookbook needs a fix there I think, as it shows referencing string fields without specifying the required sort type.

See also

- **[PHP Manual > Function Reference > Variable and Type Related Extensions > Arrays > Array Functions > sort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)**
- **[Cookbook > Collections > Sorting](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/collections.html#sorting)**